# CSS: How to center align a list element with left aligned text?

Tags: css

I am attempting to center align a list within a div, but keeping the text left aligned.

So, I want all the bullets lined up vertically (left aligned), but the entire list itself should be positioned in the center, as is the paragraph in my example below:

```css
.container { width: 600px; padding: 2em; background: #eee; }
.align-center { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="align-center">Center Align Test</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
    <li>Finally, the third and final element</li>
   </ul>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make the `ul` an `inline-block` element and center that. Then left align the text of the `li`.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="align-center">Center Align Test</p>

  <ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
    <li>Finally, the third and final element</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

---

..or use **Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.align-center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="align-center">Center Align Test</p>

  <ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
    <li>Finally, the third and final element</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a **flex** container.

```
.flex-container
{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   text-align: left;
}

<div class="flex-container">
 <ul>
    <li>Left Aligned #1</li>
    <li>Left Aligned #2</li>
    <li>Left Aligned #3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding `text-align:center` to the container `div` so that the `ul` will be centered. Then you'll need to apply `display:inline-block` to the `ul` so that it doesn't take up the whole horizontal space. Finally, add `text-align:left` to the `ul` so that the `center` does not inherit from the parent, as desired.

```css
.container { width: 600px; padding: 2em; background: #eee; text-align:center}
.align-center { text-align: center; }
ul {display:inline-block; text-align:left}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="align-center">Center Align Test</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
    <li>Finally, the third and final element</li>
   </ul>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` to the container, make the `ul` an `inline-block` and give the `ul` `text-align: left;`

```css
.container { width: 600px; padding: 2em; background: #eee; text-align: center;}
.align-center { text-align: center; }
ul { display: inline-block;  text-align: left;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="align-center">Center Align Test</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
    <li>Finally, the third and final element</li>
   </ul>
 
 </div>
```